# Is $1_1,1_2,1_3$ different from $1_2,1_3,1_1$ in a permutation?

Tags: combinatorics

This is from problem 1 in Introduction to Probability by Joseph K Blitzstein and Jessica Hwang.

> 1. How many ways are there to permute the letters in the word MISSISSIPPI?

My answer was 11!. I'm reading that it should be $11! \over 4!4!2!$. My understanding is that a permutation is unique as long as the order of the values are separate. eg: $1_1,1_2,1_3$ is different from $1_3,1_1,1_2$

Is that not correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but isn't the point here that the letters S (or I or P) in MISSISSIPPI are **in**distinguishable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; $1_1 1_2 1_3$ would be different from $1_3 1_1 1_2$ because there the symbols are *labeled*.  However, the letters in MISSISSIPPI are *not* labeled.  The word

MISSISSIPPI

is indistinguishable from the word

MISSISSIPPI

even though I've secretly switched the first two S's in the second word.  The two $S$'s are not distinguishable.

Here we are considering permutations of a *word*, which may have repeatedly letters, as opposed to a permutation of a *set*, which has distinct elements.  The definitions are different.